# Direct link to web archive's first copy of a url

Tags: website, archive.org

Very often I will visit the link eg web.archive.org/web/___example.org__ 
to see the server's latest copy of a  webpage.

What's the direct method to do the same  for the first copy of the webpage?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you specify a timestamp in the URL then the Wayback Machine gives you the snapshot closest to that timestamp, so you can get the earliest timestamp by specifying a really early time, i.e https://web.archive.org/web/1950/http://example.com/

Comment: btw did they put this in the docs or is it liable to break at any time?

Comment: Not aware of any documentation, but the web archive of all places seems extremely unlikely to break links